# JSF conditional styling does not work in the runtime

Tags: jsf

I'm trying to do a conditional styling on a JSF application and trying to implement it as follows

```
<h:inputText id="contact_phone2" value="#{jobs_Builder.selected.contactPhone2}" title="#{lbl.ContactPhone2}" binding="#{phoneNumberValidator.myComponent}" style="#{phoneNumberValidator.valid ? 'border-color:black;' : 'border-color:red;'}"/>
```

In the `PhoneNumberValidator.java` class I have the bellow code

```
private UIComponent myComponent;

public UIComponent getMyComponent() {
    return myComponent;
}

public void setMyComponent(UIComponent myComponent) {
    this.myComponent = myComponent;
}

public boolean isValid(){
    UIInput input = (UIInput) myComponent;
    String value = input.toString();
    return value != null && value.length() > 2;
}
```

*Note that the validation logic is dummy one and not the correct one.*

When I debug this, the validation code is hit only when the page is initially loading, so this is not working in runtime. The expected behavior is to have this in the runtime so whenever user types something, the validation logic should trigger, and based on that the styling should be changed.

Comment: Then you need to add `f:ajax` to your Input on event="keyup" if you want the component to update after each keypress it will re-evaluate your `style` EL.

Comment: Still no luck. Now my code looks like this. I have added `<f:ajax event="keyup"/>`

Comment: Don't forget you have to render the input box in the ajax with `<f:ajax event="keyup" render="@this"/> `